# Vue cli 3 project alias src to @ or ~/ not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

I have installed the project with `vue cli 3` but as the project grows, the import on the components are getting ugly, I end up importing a component like

```
import Component from '../../../../components/folder/Component.vue'
```

I just want to alias the src folder and do

```
import Component from '@components/folder/Component.vue'
```

I did read that I have to modify the `vue.config.js`, I have done it but the error is the same

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@components/Permissions/PermissionsTable'
```

This is my vue.config.js

```
  const path = require("path");

  const vueSrc = "./src";

  module.exports = {
    runtimeCompiler: true,
    css: {
      modules: true
    },
    configureWebpack: {
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          "@": path.join(__dirname, vueSrc)
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Am I missing something? What else should I do?

Comment: A project generated with Vue CLI should already have that alias available without any additional configuration.

Comment: It’s built in to the CLI, can you try `import Component from '@/components/folder/Component.vue'`?

Answer (score 11):

For Vue CLI you need to create a file in the root folder of project - jsconfig.json

```
{
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and that's all, helped me with PhpStorm

Comment: This should actually be the correct answer...adding `extensions` to the vite configdoes not do anything.

Comment: @NoopurPhalak, I didn't check how it works with Vite. 
With Vue 2.6 and @vue/cli 5.0.1 still working for for me.

The question was asked more than 3 year ago, so probably you should find another solution.

Comment: It works fine with vite as well. That is why I said, previously that this answer should be the accepted one. Actually even for @vue/cli this should have been the correct answer at that time...

Answer (score 7):

I was missing `extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],` and in the import I have to use `'@/components/...'`

Comment: Can you give your entire webpack configutation code so other people with same issue/question can rely on ? ty

Answer (score 7):

The complete example:

```
const path = require("path");
const vueSrc = "./src";
module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  css: {
    modules: true
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "@": path.resolve(__dirname, vueSrc)
      },
      extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json']
    }
  }
};
```

Although I am not sure that extensions is the solution to the problem you had. This will just add the extensions in case you haven't written those in the import definition:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions

I have a feeling it was rather a problem with the missing `/`. So instead of `@components/Permissions/PermissionsTable` it should have been `@/components/Permissions/PermissionsTable` because you did not add a `/` at the end of your `vueSrc`. So webpack will just attach it to `./src` like this: `./srccomponents/Permissions/PermissionsTable`.