# cant load image with img bind vue

Tags: image, vue.js, bind

can anyone help me, why my image won't load ?

```
<div class="card" v-for="movie in movies_trend" v-bind:key="movie.id" >
    <div :class="['card-movie', movie.page]" :movie="movie.name">
        <img :src="'../src/assets/image/kimi-no-na-wa-poster.jpg'+movie.poster" class="card-img-top" :alt="movie.name">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my dir

[image]

Comment: Incorrect path `../assets/image/yourimage`, generally you want to create an alias to the root dir so you don't have to do this up and down code for directories.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55309945/vue-cli-3-project-alias-src-to-or-not-working

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="card" v-for="movie in movies_trend" v-bind:key="movie.id" >
    <div :class="['card-movie', movie.page]" :movie="movie.name">
        <img :src="movie.poster" class="card-img-top" :alt="movie.name">
    </div>
</div>
```

your path of an image can be added to **movie.poster**
so your **movie.poster** will contain value '../src/assets/image/kimi-no-na-wa-poster.jpg'

you can add image tag in the following way also

```
<img :src="'../src/assets/image/'+ ${movie.poster}" class="card-img-top" :alt="movie.name"/>
```

In this case, your variable **movie.poster** will container only the name of image **kimi-no-na-wa-poster.jpg**